# Slice storage reference in Go

Tags: go

In the Go library source you often see that a slice is passed by creating a new slice storage reference like so

```
method(s[:])
```

What's the benefit of this, compared to just passing the original slice?

```
method(s)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `s[:]` construct is normally used only to create a new slice referencing an existing array, not for "passing the original slice".

If `s[:]` is really used somewhere in the stdlib and `s` is a slice than it could be e.g. a refactoring leftover. Please report such place if known to you on the Go [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list).

Comment: You should not use `s[:]` for `s` of a slice type.

Comment: Ah ok. So It's only used if `s` is an array and not a slice yet.

Answer (score 1):

The only case where you would see code like this is when s is an array, and you want to pass as a parameter to a function that takes a slice as its input. Take the following code.

```
package main
func main() {
    x := [...]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    someFunction(x)   // type mismatch error : expecting [] int, passed [5] int 
    someFunction(x[:])// no error   
}

func someFunction(input []int){
    // use input 
}
```

The thing to note here is that [] int and [5] int are entirely different types.